# Copy value to readonly field in tfs xml

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I'm working on the Azure DevOps server process template, I have a requirement where I need to copy values to a read-only field based on the selection of another picklist field.

I tried in multiple ways, not finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is doable.

in the web layout you can make the field as readonly, here is the syntax
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops#attributes

```
<Control FieldName="FieldName" Type="DateTimeControl | ExtensionsControl |  
FieldControl | HtmlFieldControl | LabelControl | WebpageControl"  
Label="LabelText" EmptyText="TextString" 
ReadOnly="True | False" Name="InstanceName" />
```

In the field section, you can have copy syntax
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-default-copy-value-field?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops